# how to pass variable from typescript to embedded JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a situation where I am using the JavaScript in my angular project and unable to work with the variables to have the dynamic behavior, is there a way I could use the ***this.testID***, which I receive from a service and then pass it to the below JS code where I am currently having a static value of ***1234***. Please let me know your suggestions/solutions.

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.testID = this.someSettings.testID; // this is the ID to be passed to below JS 
  }

  public onClicked() {
    let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = `text/javascript`;
    script.text = `{          
      window._fs = window._fs || [];
      _fs.push(['cid', 'something']);
      _fs.push(['uid', '1234']); // here is where I want the ID from above to be passed instead of 1234
    }`;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: `_fs.push(['uid', this.testID])` ?

Comment: that didn't work, I have tried it.

Comment: It's in a backtick string, try `\`_fs.push(['uid', ${this.testID} ])\``

Comment: @JeremyThille this causes it to not identify _fs, it says "Cannot find name '_fs'."

Comment: What do you mean you didn't need the backticks? Your string is already in backticks, and you posted my solution yourself using backticks

Comment: @JeremyThille I might have confused, please use post your answer, so that I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, no worries, did so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole `script.text` is in backticks, that is, a type of strings that support multiline and interpreted values in them :

```
script.text = `{  // <--- Starting backtick        
      window._fs = window._fs || [];
      _fs.push(['cid', 'something']);
      _fs.push(['uid', ${this.testID}]); //  <-- Interpreted value
}`;  // <--- Ending backtick
```